# Replace column values with group by and condition on another column using R

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I have a large dataset that essentially looks like so:

```
ex <- data.frame(member = c(rep(1234,5)),
                 caseid = c(72,74,78,72,78),
                 code = c(2270,2508,2270,2134,2984),
                 pay = c(90,120,40,60,200))
```

I would like to find a way to replace the value in *code* with the code value corresponding to the row with the highest pay, while being grouped by the *caseid* column. The output that I would like would be like this:

```
ex1 <- data.frame(member = c(rep(1234,5)),
                  caseid = c(72,74,78,72,78),
                  code = c(2270,2508,2984,2270,2984),
                  pay = c(90,120,40,60,200))
```

I am trying to update the code column based on the *pay* column. So since row 1 has the highest pay of 90, replace row 4 with code 2270

Is there a way I could do this using data.table or tidyverse? The actual dataset has multiple members with different caseids so I would like something that could also group by member id to apply these changes by each member as well.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ex %>% group_by(caseid) %>% mutate(code = max(code))`

Comment: @RonakShah mutate(code = max(code)) will replace the code column with the highest code value, but how can I do it so it's based on the highest pay? For example, if row 1 with code 2006 had a pay of 90, how could I replace row 4 with 2006 since the pay in that row is 60?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `arrange` your data based on decreasing `pay` value and assign the `first` code value for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

ex %>%
  arrange(caseid, desc(pay)) %>%
  group_by(member, caseid) %>%
  mutate(code = first(code))

#  member caseid  code   pay
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   1234     72  2270    90
#2   1234     72  2270    60
#3   1234     74  2508   120
#4   1234     78  2984   200
#5   1234     78  2984    40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `code` value in-place as below:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(ex)
ex[, code:=code[which.max(pay)], by=caseid][]
#>    member caseid code pay
#> 1:   1234     72 2270  90
#> 2:   1234     74 2508 120
#> 3:   1234     78 2984  40
#> 4:   1234     72 2270  60
#> 5:   1234     78 2984 200
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>